SeatMap.js:21 Error fetching seats: Error: no matching fragment (operation="fragment", info={ "args": [ null ], "key": "seatsTaken" },
I have been try to see the values in my array from a function i created with solidity in my APP.js:
mapping(uint256 => uint256[]) public seatsTaken; 
function getSeatsTaken(uint256 _matchID) public view returns (uint256[] memory) { 
    return seatsTaken[_matchID];
}

App.js
function App() {
  
  const [provider, setProvider] = useState(null)
  const [account, setAccount] = useState(null)

  const [courtPass, setCourtPass] = useState(null)
  const [match, setMatch] = useState([])

  const [matches, setMatches] = useState([])
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState([false])

  
    const connectToEthereumAccount = async () => {
      const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum)
      setProvider(provider)

      const network = await provider.getNetwork()
      const address = config[network.chainId].CourtPass.address
      const courtPass = new ethers.Contract(address, CourtPass, provider)
      setCourtPass(courtPass)
      console.log("courtPass iniitialised from App.js:", courtPass);  // Add this line

      const matchCounter = await courtPass.matchCounter()
      const matches = []

      for (var i = 1; i <= matchCounter; i++) {
        const match = await courtPass.getMatch(i)
        matches.push(match)
      }
      setMatches(matches)

      window.ethereum.on('accountsChanged', async () => {
        const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
        const account = ethers.getAddress(accounts[0]);
        setAccount(account);

      })
    }
    

    useEffect(() => {
    connectToEthereumAccount();
    //SeatChart();
  }, [])
  
  console.log("Image URL:", match.imageUrl);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h2 className="header__title"><strong>Match</strong> Tickets</h2>
        <Navigation account={account} setAccount={setAccount} />
      </header> 
      

      <div className='cards'>
        {matches.map((match, matchID) => (
          <MatchCard
            match={match}
            matchID={matchID}
            courtPass={courtPass}
            provider={provider}
            account={account}
            toggle = {toggle}
           setToggle={(value) => setToggle(value)}
           setMatch={setMatch}
           key={matchID}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
      
      {toggle && courtPass && match && (
  <SeatChart
    match={match}
    courtPass={courtPass}
    provider={provider}
    setToggle={setToggle}
  />
)}
</div>
  );
}

export default App;

seatChart.js
const SeatChart = ({ match, courtPass, provider, setToggle }) => {
  const [seatsTaken, setSeatsTaken] = useState();
  const [hasSold, setHasSold] = useState(false);

  const getSeatsTaken = async () => {
    if (!courtPass || !match) {
      console.error('courtPass or match is not initialized');
      return;
    }
  
    try {
      let seats = await courtPass.seatsTaken(match._matchID);
      
  
      setSeatsTaken(seats);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching seats:', error);
    }
  };
  
  

  const buyHandler = async (_seat) => {
    setHasSold(false);

    const signer = await provider.getSigner();
    const transaction = await courtPass.connect(signer).purchaseTickets(match._matchID, _seat, { value: match.ticketPrice });
    await transaction.wait();
    setHasSold(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (courtPass) {
      getSeatsTaken();
    }
  }, [courtPass, hasSold]);

  if (!courtPass) {
    return <div>Loading courtPass... wait</div>;
  }


const getSeatsTaken = async () => {
if (!courtPass || !match) {
console.error('courtPass or match is not initialized');
return;
}
try {
let seats = await courtPass.getSeatsTaken(match._matchID);
setSeatsTaken(seats);
} catch (error) {
console.error('Error fetching seats:', error);
}
};
i tried this, its still not working
